# How to find propagation delay for this circuit?

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

How would one find the WORST case propagation delay for the circuit belowO(indicating the input and output and delay)?
CD74HCT32 - High Speed CMOS Logic Quad Two-Input OR Gates and 
CD74HCT08 - High Speed CMOS Logic Quad 2-Input AND Gates are being used. Thanks!

Also would their be a way to make this circuit into a Verilog structural style module? Sorry for asking very new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheets of [CD74HCT08](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct08.pdf) and [CD74HCT32](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct32.pdf) contain tables labelled "Switching Specifications". Input to output delay of both gates is 135ns at worst case.

Since there are 6 gates (excluding inverters) on the longest path, its delay should be 810ns at worst case (temperature: 125C, load: 50pF, Vcc: 2V, type: HC).